# Get nth host from inventory_hostname in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, inventory

Below is how my inventory hosts file looks like.

```
[all_hosts]
server1 USER=user1
server3 USER=user2
server5 USER=user1
…..
```

In my ansible playbook I wish to always refer to the first host i.e `server1` and `USER=user1` for a `copy` task because the file to be copied always resides on the first host in the `inventory_hostname`. Consider `-e domain_home=all_hosts`

```
---

- name: "Play 1"

  hosts: "{{ domain_home }}"
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Although the inventory hostname is {{ inventory_hostname }} the first host will always be  <need help get first host> and the user will always be <need help get user for first host>
```

Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

The `groups["all_hosts"]` fact is ordered by their position in the .ini file, so you can just ask for the `[0]`th item (or use the `| first` filter), and then the hostvars `dict` is similarly indexed by their names

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
     Although the inventory hostname is {{ inventory_hostname }}
     the first host will always be {{ host0 }}
     and the user will always be {{ hostvars[host0].USER }}
  vars:
    host0: '{{ groups[domain_home][0] }}'
```

In the future, to help teach yourself to fish, `- debug: var=vars` and `- debug: var=hostvars` is illustrative to see what information is available to you at any point in the playbook